# Creating file with a blank within from a command prompt from a php script

Tags: php, windows, cmd, command-prompt

I've following problem:

I've a `PHP-script` which uses the method `proc_open`. The cmd will start an application from myself with some `parameters`. One of the parameters is a filename. If the filename contains a blank it won't work correctly, e.g. `"path/to/app.exe" U 6 file name.sth`. The third parameter 'File name.sth' should be the filename. The application which is called as the first parameter should create a new file in a given directory and this works but not with the whole filename. In my example it create a file called 'File' and that's not the whole name.

Anyone here who can help me? I also quoted the filename, e.g. `"path/to/app" U 6 "File name.sth"` but this didn't work.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer Can you give me an example. Dunno what u mean. Do u mean sth like `"path/to/app.exe" U 6 "File%name.sth"`?

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer No I'm using a `PHP-script` which is calling an application from myself and this application need three parameters. The third parameter is the important one. It's the filename the application will create. If the filename contains a blank it doesn't work well. `exam ple.txt` will not created the file called `exam ple.txt`. It only create a file which is named with `exam`...

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer Of course I will show you. I'll give u the source code tomorrow. It's on another notebook.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144515/discussion-between-premox-and-software-engineer).